# Converting from Service reference to client?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service with EF(Entity Framework) implemented to access a Product table in a database. I have a test client added in my project to display the return product when entering an ID.

Here is my Method in the service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    VareWS VareWSGet(String barcode);
```

Here is the implemented method in the service:

```
public VareWS VareWSGet(string barcode)
    {
        ExamDBEntities3 context = new ExamDBEntities3();
        var vareEntity = (from v
                             in context.Vare
                             where v.barcode == barcode
                             select v).FirstOrDefault();
        if (vareEntity != null)
            return TranslateProductEntityToProduct(vareEntity);
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid product id");
    }
```

Here is the private method used to translate the product entity:

```
private VareWS TranslateProductEntityToProduct(
              Vare vareEntity)
    {
        VareWS vare = new VareWS();
        vare.navn = vareEntity.navn;
        vare.pris = (int)vareEntity.pris;
        return vare;
    }
```

In my client I use this code to call the method in my web service:

```
sc = new Service1Client();
        string inputID = TextBox1.Text;
        VareWS v = sc.VareWSGet(inputID);
```

The service reference have been added succesfully, however I am getting an error saying "cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.VareWS' to 'VareWS'"
I am unsure how to correct this error, since I have specified a connection to my service client. Let me know if you need more information, thanks.

Using statements:

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ExamOpg.ServiceReference2;
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
```

Comment: Can I see the using statements, all of them, in that file?

Comment: Here are the using statements for the client:

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ExamOpg.ServiceReference2;

Comment: Sorry, my formatting seems to have failed, I'll add them in the original post.

Comment: Do you have `VareWS` in `ExamOpg.ServiceReference2` also?

Comment: Yes, as can be seen here: http://puu.sh/t7XVv/009a5e98d3.png

Comment: So did it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to your using statement:

```
using ExamOpg.ServiceReference2;
```

Type `VareWS` will be the type `VareWS` in that namespace. But you are trying to convert the type `VareWS` from `ServiceReference1.VareWS` to that type. This is clearly not doable so you are getting that exception.

Change your using statement to `ExamOpg.ServiceReference1` or whatever the namespace is where `ServiceReference1` is.